# Where are the section headings in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard with multiple tabs, one of which I would like to write as a smart book down document. But there are no section headings, where have they gone?

Why do I expect it to look like this example? [enter link description here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/markdown-document.html)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)

```

**Contact**

aaa@abcd.edu

## What we are trying to estimate?

This is a tool whhich is designed to estimate viral dose to individual passengers on ABC under a variety of conditions.

Whilst a dose-response curve doesn't yet exist for `SARS CoV-2`, we have employed an exponential model for `HCoV229-E`, whihch is thhough to be a reasonable analogogus pathogen.

## Second sub.section
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work. The only change is the use of `###`. See here for a known bug https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/pull/250

- Change

`## What we are trying to estimate?`

to

`### What we are trying to estimate?`

- Change

`## Second sub.section`

to

`### Second sub.section`